# Can't switch image on jquery drop

Tags: jquery

I'm new to this forum but I'll try my best to be as specific as possible.

I seem to have some trouble by trying to switch an image by trying to change the src-attr. in jQuery). I guess (=know) that the problem lays within the dropevents in my jQuery-code. My goal is to drag a dragger over a wide container, with 5 smaller containers in it. When the dragger is dropped on one of the smaller containers, I want it to change an image that it positioned above the whole drag element.

I have tried to make a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yuj9apyy/11/ . Here, it doesn't work perfectly because of the positions and stuff, but you can get the idea! Also, I didn't succeed adding the image that has to be changed...

Here's the relevant HTML:

```
//This is the image I would like to change the src-attr. from.
    <div id="grafiek">
        <img src="Afb/GrafiekDord2010.png" id="grafiekDord2010"/>
    </div>

//This is the bigContainer, container 5 smaller containers, some numbers along it (these 
are not of any influence), and a dragger.

    <div id="bigContainer"> 
        <span id="container1" class="drop1"></span><span id="container2" class="drop1"></span><span id="container3" class="drop1"></span><span id="container4" class="drop1"></span><span id="container5" class="drop1"></span><p id="jaartallen">2010 2015 2020 2025 2030</p>
        <div id="dragger"></div>
    </div>
```

All the positions and widths/heights are specified in the CSS-code.All those span-containers are positioned next to each other and exactly fill up the space of the bigContainer. The dragger is a small black container itself, and is horizontally draggable within the width of the bigContainer.

Below is the jQuery. Now I have to say I'm very new with this, and did all searching through some -kind-of-tutorial-website. It may be that I'm on the right path, but being totally wrong wouldn't surprise me...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#bigContainer")
  .delegate('#dragger',"draginit", function(ev, drag){
    ev.preventDefault();
    drag.horizontal();
    drag.limit($("#bigContainer"));
    drag.step(34.4,$("#bigContainer"),"x")
  })
//This above actually works perfectly! Took some efford...

$("#bigContainer")
    .delegate('.drop1', "dropon", function(ev, drop, drag) {
        $('#grafiekDord2010').attr("src").replace("Afb/GrafiekDord2015.png", ".png");
        $(this).attr("src", src);
    })
//The class drop1 being delegated to, is the class given to every small container.
});
//And this doesn't work...at all.
```

I figured the CSS isn't important. If it is, let me know and I'll post it.

Thanks in advance for any answers! I appreciate the efford everybody puts in just to help someone :) If you need any more code / information, let me know!

Comment: BTW there is an option to include a runnable code snippet. If you [edit] the question and add a demo it'd be easier to help.

Comment: Thanks, I did that know!

Answer (score 0):

This maybe not a complete answer but points out some particular issues.

1) Inside your `dropon`- callback you get the src-attribute of `$('#grafiekDord2010')` but don't store it somewhere so its lost at once. 2) I don't know exactly to what element the keyword `this` points to but shurely not to `$('#grafiekDord2010')`. So if you want to change the src the function should look like this:

```
$("#bigContainer").delegate('.drop1', "dropon", function(ev, drop, drag) {
    var grafiek = $('#grafiekDord2010'),
        newsrc = grafiek.attr("src").replace("Afb/GrafiekDord2015.png", ".png");
    grafiek.attr("src", newsrc);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, after a lot of searching yesterday, I figured it out myself. It turns out it was even easier than the solution of TJ.

$('#bigContainer').delegate ('#container1', 'dropover', function (ev, drop, drag){ 
    $('.grafiek1').attr('src','Afb/GrafiekDord2010.png');
})

So the bigcontainer delegates to its smaller container, which I gave classes but also ID's. Unfortunately, delegating to the class didn't do the trick. Then, when it drops (/drags) over the container1, it searches the image by class and changes the src.attr to another image!

Works perfectly.